# Long SQL query with much duplication between two halves of a UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

This works, but it's huge.

We need to repeat each table column on each `UNION SELECT`, as well as the `WHERE` clause for `DATE` comparison.

```
( 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(APA_T.district), t.name 
FROM tbl_activity AS t 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap ON t.id = ap.activity_id 
INNER JOIN ( 
SELECT DISTINCT apa.district AS district, ( 
SELECT s1.activity_package_id 
FROM tbl_activity_package_address s1 
WHERE apa.district = s1.district 
ORDER BY s1.id DESC 
LIMIT 1 
) AS idActivityPackage 
FROM 
tbl_activity_package_address apa 
ORDER BY apa.district 
) AS APA_T 
ON ap.id = APA_T.idActivityPackage 
WHERE (ap.publication_date <= CURDATE()) 
AND (DATE_ADD(ap.publication_date, INTERVAL ap.publication_duration_in_days DAY) >= CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY t.name 
ORDER BY APA_T.district 
) 
UNION DISTINCT 
( 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT apa2.district ORDER BY apa2.district), t2.name 
FROM tbl_activity AS t2 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap2 ON t2.id = ap2.activity_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package_address AS apa2 ON ap2.id = apa2.activity_package_id 
WHERE (ap2.publication_date <= CURDATE()) 
AND (DATE_ADD(ap2.publication_date, INTERVAL ap2.publication_duration_in_days DAY) >= CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY t2.name 
ORDER BY apa2.district 
) 
LIMIT 6, 6
```

I have removed the WHERE CLAUSE for DATE comparisons, because I can't have it on this fiddle structure, but, the repetition is still an issue. I've been told about INTERSECT but found nothing about that on MySQL.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37dd94/51

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL Fiddle and the question have inconsistent column names: the fiddle has `id_activity_package`, while the code in this question has `activity_package_id`.  I'll consider the fiddle as supplementary information, and treat the code in the question as authoritative.

---

The two halves of the `UNION` are nearly identical, with the exception of the second `INNER JOIN`.  Let's analyze it one step at a time.

1. In the first half of the `UNION`, you join with `APA_T`, which is…

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT apa.district AS district,
       (SELECT s1.activity_package_id
           FROM tbl_activity_package_address s1
           WHERE apa.district = s1.district
           ORDER BY s1.id DESC
           LIMIT 1
       ) AS idActivityPackage
       FROM tbl_activity_package_address apa 
       ORDER BY apa.district
   ```

   The `DISTINCT` there is superfluous, since the innermost `SELECT` is guaranteed to return at most one row per `district`.

   As I read it, `APA_T` is a subquery that lists the most recently added `activity_package_id` for each `district`.  I think it's worth creating a view for clarity.

   ```
   CREATE VIEW latest_activity_package_address AS
   SELECT *
       FROM tbl_activity_package_address
       WHERE id IN (
           SELECT MAX(id)
               FROM tbl_activity_package_address AS latest_apa
               GROUP BY district
       );
   ```

   Then, the first half of the `UNION` becomes:

   ```
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(district ORDER BY district), t.name
       FROM tbl_activity AS t
           INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap
               ON t.id = ap.activity_id
           INNER JOIN latest_activity_package_address AS apa
               ON ap.id = apa.activity_package_id
       WHERE (ap.publication_date <= CURDATE())
           AND (DATE_ADD(ap.publication_date, INTERVAL ap.publication_duration_in_days DAY) >= CURDATE())
       GROUP BY t.name
       ORDER BY apa.district
   ```

   I've copied the `ORDER BY` clause into the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, where I think it belongs.
2. Next, I'd like to point out that `LIMIT 6,6` will produce non-deterministic results, since there is no `ORDER BY` clause on the `UNION` query.  You've put an `ORDER BY` on each half of the `UNION`, but [that doesn't guarantee that the result will be ordered the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473427/1157100).
3. Surprisingly, I haven't found a way to reduce duplication between the two halves of the `UNION`.  However, there is now a nice parallelism which may be more aesthetically pleasing.  You don't need to select new table aliases for the second half; they aren't in the same scope as the first half.

   ```
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(district ORDER BY district), t.name
       FROM tbl_activity AS t
           INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap
               ON t.id = ap.activity_id
           INNER JOIN latest_activity_package_address AS apa
               ON ap.id = apa.activity_package_id
       WHERE (ap.publication_date <= CURDATE())
           AND (DATE_ADD(ap.publication_date, INTERVAL ap.publication_duration_in_days DAY) >= CURDATE())
       GROUP BY t.name
       ORDER BY apa.district
   UNION DISTINCT
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(district ORDER BY district), t.name
       FROM tbl_activity AS t
           INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap
               ON t.id = ap.activity_id
           INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package_address AS apa
               ON ap.id = apa.activity_package_id
       WHERE (ap.publication_date <= CURDATE())
           AND (DATE_ADD(ap.publication_date, INTERVAL ap.publication_duration_in_days DAY) >= CURDATE())
       GROUP BY t.name
       ORDER BY apa.district
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time analysing the code. Please allow me some time to study.

Answer (score 2):

The nesting is incomprehensible without indentation.  For your benefit and for the benefit of anyone attempting to review this code, I've reformatted the code, changing nothing but whitespace.

```
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(APA_T.district), t.name
        FROM tbl_activity AS t
            INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap
                ON t.id = ap.activity_id
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT apa.district AS district,
                    (SELECT s1.activity_package_id
                        FROM tbl_activity_package_address s1
                        WHERE apa.district = s1.district
                        ORDER BY s1.id DESC
                        LIMIT 1
                    ) AS idActivityPackage
                    FROM tbl_activity_package_address apa 
                    ORDER BY apa.district
            ) AS APA_T
                ON ap.id = APA_T.idActivityPackage
        WHERE (ap.publication_date <= CURDATE())
            AND (DATE_ADD(ap.publication_date, INTERVAL ap.publication_duration_in_days DAY) >= CURDATE())
        GROUP BY t.name
        ORDER BY APA_T.district
)
UNION DISTINCT
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT apa2.district ORDER BY apa2.district), t2.name
        FROM tbl_activity AS t2
            INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap2
                ON t2.id = ap2.activity_id
            INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package_address AS apa2
                ON ap2.id = apa2.activity_package_id
        WHERE (ap2.publication_date <= CURDATE())
            AND (DATE_ADD(ap2.publication_date, INTERVAL ap2.publication_duration_in_days DAY) >= CURDATE())
        GROUP BY t2.name
        ORDER BY apa2.district
)
LIMIT 6, 6
```

Comment: I have edit my question with your indentation work. Thanks.

Comment: Edit rolled back. [Code in a question must be preserved](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1816/9357), so as not to invalidate answers.

Comment: It was preserved. Changing spaces will do nothing, but clarification. :) You suggest a edit, and I've done it. :) No? I believe your answer serves more an edit to the OP question. But that's my 2 cents. :) No issues either way.

Comment: No. As mentioned in the meta post that I linked to, all facets of the code are subject to review, _including whitespace_.

Comment: I understand. Even if, the answer doesn't answer all, it answers some parts of it, by reviewing some parts of the code. It makes sense on a "code review" stackexchange. :)